# Cydia Repo "The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 1 NODATA 2"

Tags: repository, gnupg, cydia

Can anyone help us to check why our Cydia repo always generate an error message "GPG error,  Release: The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 1 NODATA 2
When add the source to Cydia or the Cydia sour Reload.

Our repo url is http://ikeymonitor.com/apt

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I haven't experienced anything unusual when adding your repo.
I can even install the iLostFinder without any problems.
Where is your repo hosted? If it's at home, you need to note that some services dosen't work indside the local network. I don't know if that does also count cydia repos. But try using another network and/or another iPad/iPhone.

Comment: The thing is how to get rid, and what do mean the NODATA 1 NODATA 2 issue. Nobody in nowhere knows how to fix it (server side - how to have the right signatures), and what do it means

Comment: I don't understand whare you see that? I haven't got any errors and i can't see any problems with your repo... Can you explain where you see this error?

Comment: That is not my repo, this is a question i found, and shot a bounty, because i always have this problem with my personal repo, and it bother me...

Comment: But where do you get this error. If this repo has the same problem I don't understand where you have seen this error?

Comment: try to add this: [http://apt-ghaschel.webatu.com/repo](http://apt-ghaschel.webatu.com/repo) it will return you NODATA 1 NODATA 2